# How to pass context to AdMob InterstitialAd in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, admob

Does smb knows how to pass a context to InterstitialAd in LibGDX?

In Android it is simply

```
InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
```

My class extended from `Screen`. or I can intialize it in class extended `Game`.. Or how to pass the context in this case?

And if smb knows any problem related to this, I'll be very thankfull to any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show ads from inside other classes not from the main activity you need to use a facade. Basically, you make use of a listener to load/display the ads.

Follow this [libgdx official tutorial guide](https://github.com/TheInvader360/tutorial-libgdx-google-ads). It covers both banner and interstitial ads and it isn't outdated. It uses the new admob via the google play services

Comment: thanks for the answer... but it doesn't solve my problem... my game extends Game class and I have Screens, so how I suppose to make it?
I'm not extending any class from android... even activity or smthg...
please, I'm confused of it

Comment: You're just not following the instructions there. If you follow the instructions, the code for your ads will go in your -android project where you will have access to the android context.

Comment: @Barodapride, okay, I'm currently out of my home, I'll keep trying! thank you for advice!

Comment: Barodapride is right. If it's libgdx the tutorial should help you. You can download it and inspect the code.